# Why doesn't the << operator defined inside a namespace participate in overload resolution?

Tags: c++, namespaces, operator-overloading, overload-resolution, name-lookup

In the following scenario, the `operator<<` function participates in overload resolution (when it is in the global namespace):

```cpp
template <typename T>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const std::vector<T> &vec) {
    os << '[';
    for (const T &val : vec)
        os << val << ", ";
    return os << "\b\b]";
}
```

... but below, when defined inside a namespace, it does not:

```cpp
namespace blah {
    template <typename T>
    std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const std::vector<T> &vec) {
        os << '[';
        for (const T &val : vec)
            os << val << ", ";
        return os << "\b\b]";
    }
}
```

When called from `main`, as such:

```cpp
int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec{5, 4, 3, 6, 4, 3, 5, 6, 8, 1};
    std::cout << vec << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

... the compiler is not able to find the `operator<<` overload when it is defined in `blah`.

What is going on?

Edit:

When calling the overload with the scope resolution operator, everything compiles fine:

```cpp
blah::operator<<(std::cout, vec);
```

Why is this?

Comment: How can the operator declared in the user namespace be found without qualifying it?

Comment: [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl).

Comment: Indeed, but what I then do not understand is why an operator overload such as `<<` defined for custom classes can remain within the namespace the classes are defined in, and still be found during lookup?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first case, there is used unqualified name lookup and/or ADL (argument-dependent lookup) lookup that includes the global namespace where the operator is declared.

In the second case, the operator will not be found because the namespace `blah` is not considered for unqualified name lookup.

Either you could use qualified the name, like:

```
blah::operator <<( std::cout, vec ) << std::endl;
```

Or, you could use a `using` directive to include the namespace `blah` in the set of namespaces for unqualified name lookup, as:

```
using namespace blah;
std::cout << vec << std::endl;
```

Comment: Indeed, although you sure don't seem like a beginner! :)

Comment: @GregorHartlWatters In Russia nobody suggests me a job because everyone thinks that I know too little.

Comment: well, it seems like you know quite a lot, so I'm sure you will find a job eventually!